# DHT11 Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno

Tags: arduino

I am having a problem with is Arduino code. It is a project called the Segment LED show temperature & humidity. The Arduino board that I am using is a Uno Freaduino 2016 board. Connecting to it is a 7-segment display with 4 pins: GND, CLK, DIO, VCC and a temperature and humidity sensor to the pin analog 0 (A0).

But that part is fine it is the code. I am using the Arduino program to write it but there is an error.

The error:

```
Arduino: 1.8.2 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

E:\Code examples\Coding examples\Arduino\Segment_LED_Show_Temperatures_Humidity\Segment_LED_Show_Temperatures_Humidity.ino:3:19: fatal error: DHT11.h: No such file or directory

#include "DHT11.h"

       ^

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
 option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

The code:

```cpp
//variables
#include "DHT11.h"
#include "TM1637.h"
#define CLK4
#define DIO5
TM1637 tm1637(CLK, DIO);
DHT11 dht11(A0);

void setup() {
  tm1637.init();
  tm1637.set(BRIGHT_TYPICAL);
}

void loop() {
  dht11.start();
  tm1637.display(3,12);
  tm1637.display(2, (dht11.DHT11data)[2] % 10);
  tm1637.display(1, (dht11.DHT11data)[2] % 100 / 10);
  delay(1000);
  tm1637.clearDisplay();
  tm1637.display(3, (dht11.DHT11data)[0] % 10);
  tm1637.display(2, (dht11.DHT11data)[0] % 100 / 10);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error:

```
#include "DHT11.h"

       ^
```

... Indicates that the specified .h file is not found.

Perhaps you need to install a [DHT11 Arduino driver package](https://github.com/adidax/dht11).

With driver package properly installed, perhaps the line should instead be:

```
#include <dht11.h>
```